# buddypress mb_substr is not working with bp_activity_content_body()

Tags: php, buddypress

I try to get `first 5` `characters` of `bp_activity_content_body()` but not working.

```
$result = mb_substr(bp_activity_content_body(), 0, 5);
```

please help me.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code for BuddyPress functions by googling them and looking at the Github repo or sites like hookr.io.

```
function bp_activity_content_body() {
    echo bp_get_activity_content_body();
}
```

So, bp_activity_content_body() does not return a value, it just echoes the content returned by bp_get_activity_content_body(). Try using bp_get_activity_content_body() in your code instead.